# Pyspark DataFrame - using LIKE function based on column name instead of string value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the `like` function on a Column with another Column. Is it possible to use `Column` inside the like function?

**sample code:**

```
df['col1'].like(concat('%',df2['col2'], '%'))
```

**Error log:**

> py4j.Py4JException: Method like([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
> does not exist
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using a SQL expression instead.  For some reason the python API doesn't directly support it.  For example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

data = [
    ("aaaa", "aa"),
    ("bbbb", "cc")
]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["value", "pattern"])
df = df.withColumn("match", expr("value like concat('%', pattern, '%')"))
df.show()
```

Outputs this:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
|value|pattern|match|
+-----+-------+-----+
| aaaa|     aa| true|
| bbbb|     cc|false|
+-----+-------+-----+
```