# How to use LIKE operator as a JOIN condition in pyspark as a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I would like to do the following in pyspark (for AWS Glue jobs):

```
JOIN a and b ON a.name = b.name AND a.number= b.number AND a.city LIKE b.city
```

So for example:

**Table a:**

| Number | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Bob | % |
| 2000 | Joe | London |

**Table b:**

| Number | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Bob | Boston |
| 1000 | Bob | Berlin |
| 2000 | Joe | Paris |

**Results**

| Number | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Bob | Boston |
| 1000 | Bob | Berlin |

So the part I don't know how to do is to implement the wildcard "%" and use the LIKE operator. I know you can use `.like()` on strings, for example:

```
df.where(col('col1').like("%string%")).show()
```

But it expects a string, where in my case I would like to do it as a column. Something like the following:

```
result = a.join(
    b,
    (a.name == b.name) &
    (a.number == b.number) &
    (a.city.like(b.city)) # <-- This doesnt work since it is not a string
```

Any help to do this will be very appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark DataFrame - using like function based on column name instead of String value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626390/pyspark-dataframe-using-like-function-based-on-column-name-instead-of-string-v)

Comment: @blackbishop Thanks for the suggestion, now I know it does, but when I was searching I didn't know that expr() could be used as a condition in the join, so the answer below may be useful to someone like me :)

Comment: IMO it's not a duplicate because it involves a join here, and there is also a mistake in the joining expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an expression:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = a.alias('a').join(
    b.alias('b'),
    (a.name == b.name) &
    (a.number == b.number) &
    F.expr("b.city like a.city")
)
```

I think you meant to do `b like a` rather than `a like b` because the `%` is in table a.